# silverstripe install with mysql socket

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, silverstripe

I´m trying to install Silverstripe on a Server with the MySQL Connection Details like following:

**Hostname** localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock

**Socket** /tmp/mysql5.sock

Entering one of these addresses in the Install Form for Database server brings up following error on submit for localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock:

```
I couldn't find a database server on 'localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock': Connection refused"
```

or for /tmp/mysql5.sock

```
I couldn't find a database server on '/tmp/mysql5.sock': php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

and just localhost shows this error:

```
I couldn't find a database server on 'localhost': Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported
```

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there was something wrong with the server settings:

This is what I added to `_config.php`:

```
ini_set('mysqli.default_socket', '/tmp/mysql5.sock');
```

then the db connection looked like this:

```
$databaseConfig = array(
    "type" => 'MySQLDatabase',
    "server" => 'localhost',
    "username" => 'myusername',
    "password" => 'mypassword',
    "database" => 'mydb',
    "path" => '/tmp/mysql5.sock',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to connect to a mysql server this way.
But maybe the installer fails to recognize a hostname like this, you could try to just write the _config.php file by hand and then run a /dev/build, maybe that works.

about:

```
I couldn't find a database server on 'localhost': Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported
```

SilverStripe requires a mysql database version 5, could it be that your mysql server is not up2date?

Answer (score 0):

In setting up SilverStripe and MariaDB on a Mac (Mountain Lion), all that was necessary was to put this into the _ss_environment.php file:

```
define('SS_DATABASE_SERVER', 'localhost:/opt/local/var/run/mariadb/mysqld.sock');
```

It was not necessary to change the value of 'mysqli.default_socket'.